# Statistical Tests for Comparing Populations (Only binned counts/proportions available) + Python Implementation

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, python

I'm working with Census data and I would like to compare it to the population that I am working with to see how much it differs. What are the best statistical tests to do this when working with binned counts? Ideally what I want to determine is if the distribution across the various age groups in my population is similar to that of the census.

Additionally, what's the best way of running this analysis in many smaller geographical regions (over 1000 different postal codes) and highlighting those that are the most different and the most similar?